# Attempting to Extract Sales Data from a Graph (Google Chrome Add-On)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, graph

There is an add-on I am using on Google Chrome, called AMZScoutPro. In order to gather data for my Master's degree dissertation, I will need to extract daily sales data from such a graph as shown here. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbvBx.png)

Basically, if you scroll over the graph it will show the data and the sales for that day. Can we figure out a way to extract these sales data from various graphs, sort of automating it ? I would be very grateful for your help, since it's super hard to find data normally.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do "web scraping".

1. Download the html that produces the graph to a file
2. Parse the html in the file to get the data.

Comment: Thank you very much man! I will look into this.